# How to connect to HSQLDB

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

Im planning to learn jdbc topic. I have downloaded the HSQL DB from the site and extracted the zip file. I have few queries:

1. How do we create a new database?
2. Will we be able to see the contents of the db via any tool [ just like we see in oracle ]?
3. How to know what is the driver name they have supplied?

   I have checked the weblink but could not find any solution. Please suggest.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: So [this](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html) didn't help you? What about chapter 1 of the [user guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/guide.pdf)?  Did you ask at their [help forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674)? What did a search of their [mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hsqldb.user) turn up?

Comment: See [Chapter One of the HSQLDB user guide](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#N1013D)... you should really try a little harder before posting trivial questions like this.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for [this](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html#NEWDB
>
> How to Create a new database:
>
> A new database is created automatically if it does not yet exist. Just
>   connect to the not-yet-existing database using the
>   jdbc:hsqldb:file:«database-path» URL (should replace the last part
>   with the path you want) with the user 'sa'  (or any name)  and a
>   password (can be an empty string). You will use this name and password
>   to connect again.
>
> Q: Will we be able to see the contents of the db via any tool?

No.  SQL Server tools aren't going to work with Oracle, mySQL tools aren't going to work with SQL Server ... and the primary goal of HSQLDB it to use it with JDBC etc, i.e. programmatic connections.

> Q: How to know what is the driver name they have supplied?

From the [FAQs](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html):

> HSQLDB comes with documentation, example program source code that can
>   help programers who are new to JDBC programming.
>
> Basic sample programs are in the /src/org/hsqldb/sample folder.
>
> Source code of test programs are useful examples of how to use
>   different features of JDBC and SQL. Check the sources in the
>   /src/org/hsqldb/test folder.
>
> SQL test scripts are in the /runtest folder and offer extensive
>   examples of SQL statements.
>
> HSQLDB has a standard JDBC interface. HSQLDB specific JDBC
>   documentation is included in the /doc/src folder.

The driver file is "hsqldb.jar".

Answer (score 2):

Read the complete tutorial on their documentation site [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apb.html). But below are the two important steps. I, however suggest you to ue Java DB that comes with the JDK itself from JDK 1.6 on wards. Here is the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/).

```
// Load the HSQL Database Engine JDBC driver
        // hsqldb.jar should be in the class path or made part of the current jar
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");

        // connect to the database.   This will load the db files and start the
        // database if it is not alread running.
        // db_file_name_prefix is used to open or create files that hold the state
        // of the db.
        // It can contain directory names relative to the
        // current working directory
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:"
                                           + db_file_name_prefix,    // filenames
                                           "sa",                     // username
                                           "");                      // password
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about in memory or real databases? If in memory, I've only done it using hibernate to create the database. Just set hibernate to create and it will create the tables for you.

Otherwise, can't help.